# Calculating whether a disease is probable using Bayes rule?

Tags: conditional-probability, bayes

I want to compute whether it is more probable that a patient has a disease or the contrary. If I am given the following information:

$$P(\mathrm{disease})= 0.008$$
$$P(+|\mathrm{disease})= 0.98$$
$$P(-|¬\mathrm{disease})= 0.97$$

To find the answer would it be correct to do the following:

$$\frac{0.008 \times 0.98}{(0.008 \times 0.98)+(0.992 \times 0.03)}=0.2085$$

and then calculate $1-0.2085$ to see which is larger?

Comment: Do you really need to **calculate** $1-p$ to determine which of $p$ and $1-p$ is larger? Couldn't you just **compare** $p$ to $0.5$ to decide whether $1-p$ is larger than $p$ than not? Yes, a computer **will** internally do a subtraction to determine whether $p$ is smaller than $0.5$ but human beings doing homework can tell at a glance that $0.2085 < 0.5$ and so $1-0.2085 > 0.2085$, no?  By the way, your calculations are correct, and I strongly urge you to use Bayes' formula in the form that you have used instead of the two-step method suggested in the answer by @Nameless.

Comment: @DilipSarwate, I don't see the difference between your formula and Nameless's, other than having the denominator "abstracted out" into a separate line. Do you object to calculating $P(\textrm{disease}|+)$ and $P(\neg \textrm{disease}|+), instead of just computing one and subtracting that value from one to find the other?

Comment: @MattKrause From a pedagogical viewpoint, it is better to teach students to use the formula in the way that the OP has because it emphasizes that the numerator is just one of the terms that are being added together in the denominator. Indeed, it is even worth emphasizing that it is _not_ necessary to _calculate_ $P(A\mid B)P(B)$ twice, once for the numerator and once for the denominator, when using $$P(B\mid A) = \frac{P(A\mid B)P(B)}{P(A\mid B)P(B)+P(A\mid B^c)P(B^c)}.$$ In years of teaching this stuff, I found _many_ students obtain different answers when doing the calculation twice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, everything is correct. Personally, I find it more useful to write out just what you compute:
$$P(disease|+)=\frac{P(disease) P(+|disease)}{P(+)}=0.2085,$$
where + indicates a positive test. $P(+)$ is the probability of observing a positive test result: 
$$P(+)=P(disease) P(+|disease)+P(\neg disease) P(+|\neg disease).$$

What you want to compare is
$P(disease|+)$ and $P(\neg disease|+)$, where $P(\neg disease|+)=1-P(disease|+)$, because the state is assumed to be binary (have disease or not). In the example, then, it is more likely not to have the disease, simply because the prior $P(disease)$ is so small.

Comment: Is this also correct if did the following: P(disease|+) = P(+|disease)*P(disease)/P(+). 

Where P(+)= P((+|disease) *P(disease)) + (P(+|¬disease)*P(¬disease))  

I get the following values: 0.98*0.008/((0.98*0.008)+(0.02*0.992)) = 0.283. Is this way also correct?

Comment: No, the likelihood of getting + if $\neg$disease is $P(+|\neg disease)=0.03=1-P(-|\neg disease)$. You can't use $P(-|disease)=0.02$ here. It is correct exactly how you calculated it in the question.